# How to match routes against full path?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

With this configuration:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/personal-area/', {...})
    .otherwise({'redirectTo': '/personal-area/'})
]);
```

When Im loading `/personal-area/` in browser - Angular redirects me to `/personal-area/#/personal-area/`.

How to make it recognize paths correctly?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and what do you expect to happen? From what I can see you are loading `/personal-area/` which does not trigger your when clause since the when you have will trigger on `#/personal-area/` therefore your otherwise will come into play and redirect by adding `#/personal-area/` to your path.

Comment: @RickardStaaf `/personal/` is an entry point to my SPA, but there is another entry points, where angular is used just for widgets. So I want that my routes would work only for first entry point.

Answer (score 0):

try like this by removing a slash,

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/personal-area', {...})
    .otherwise({'redirectTo': '/personal-area'})
]);
```